# How to solve the TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str error in python?

Tags: python

```
import os

txt = 1

mmyyyy =  ' -08-2020 '

for f in range (1,1001):

    for i in range (1,11) :

        if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\Hayavadan\\OneDrive\\Python\\' + str(i)  + mmyyyy):

             os.mkdir ("C:\\Users\\Hayavadan\OneDrive\Python\\" + str (i) + mmyyyy)

             open ("C:\\Users\\Hayavadan\\OneDrive\\Python\\1 -08-2020\\" + str(f) + txt , "w")

    else:
         os.rmdir ("C:\\Users\\Hayavadan\OneDrive\Python\\" + str (i) + mmyyyy)
```

The error

```
======== RESTART: C:/Users/Hayavadan/OneDrive/Python/delete by hayu 3.py =======
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hayavadan/OneDrive/Python/delete by hayu 3.py", line 8, in <module>
    open ("C:\\Users\\Hayavadan\\OneDrive\\Python\\1 -08-2020\\" + str(f) + txt , "w")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: Change txt to string

Comment: This is a somewhat common error in many languages. I would suggest to read the error messages more attentively cause this one is pretty clear on the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str(txt)` in the 8 line because you can't concatenate`string` and `int`

If you are talking about creating a text file then you should use `".txt"` instead of `str(txt)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert txt to string `".txt"`.
Here the code:

```
import os

txt = 1

mmyyyy =  ' -08-2020 '

for f in range (1,1001):

    for i in range (1,11) :

        if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\Hayavadan\\OneDrive\\Python\\' + str(i)  + mmyyyy):

             os.mkdir ("C:\\Users\\Hayavadan\OneDrive\Python\\" + str (i) + mmyyyy)

             open ("C:\\Users\\Hayavadan\\OneDrive\\Python\\1 -08-2020\\" + str(f) + ".txt" , "w")

    else:
         os.rmdir ("C:\\Users\\Hayavadan\OneDrive\Python\\" + str (i) + mmyyyy)
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the cast for txt, so change **txt** to **str(txt)**:

```
import os

txt = 1

mmyyyy =  ' -08-2020 '

for f in range (1,1001):

    for i in range (1,11) :

        if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\Hayavadan\\OneDrive\\Python\\' + str(i)  + mmyyyy):

             os.mkdir ("C:\\Users\\Hayavadan\OneDrive\Python\\" + str (i) + mmyyyy)

             open ("C:\\Users\\Hayavadan\\OneDrive\\Python\\1 -08-2020\\" + str(f) + str(txt) , "w")

    else:
         os.rmdir ("C:\\Users\\Hayavadan\OneDrive\Python\\" + str (i) + mmyyyy)
```